# MongoDB maximum wire version error due to incompatible Nodejs Driver version

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-nodejs-driver

I have downloaded and installed latest available version of MongoDB Community Server (6.0.8) on my Mac and I also installed latest Node.js driver from npm (5.7.0), but when I try to connect to my local mongodb instance I get this error:

> MongoServerSelectionError: Server at 127.0.0.1:27017 reports maximum
> wire version 5, but this version of the Node.js Driver requires at
> least 6 (MongoDB 3.6)

Why does the official MongoDB Node.js Driver require a server version that is higher than what MongoDB offers for download on their official download page? And which version of Driver is compatible with MongoDB 6.0.8?

Comment: When I unzip the mongodb tar file mongodb-macos-x86_64-6.0.8.tgz and run mongod --version in bin folder, it logs db version v3.4.3. I'm confused. Shouldn't db version be 6.0.8?

Comment: Check your $PATH and/or try running `which mongod` to see which file is actually being executed

Comment: @Joe You are right. When I run `which mongod` it logs folder `/Users/sm/mongodb/bin` which contains version 3.4.3 while I have downloaded the latest mongodb version to folder `/usr/local/mongodb` and in my $PATH the old path comes before the new path.  I don't know where the old version comes from, but I guess by removing the old path from my $PATH problem should resolve.

Comment: I couldn't simply remove the wrong path from $PATH by editing my .bash_profile. I found out that Homebrew had added the old version of Mongodb to my $PATH when I had initially tried to use Homebrew (unsuccessfully) to install Mongodb and when I installed Mongodb manually by downloading zip file I didn't realize I had to remove stuff added by Homebrew using `brew untap mongodb/brew` and `brew uninstall mongodb-database-tools`.